# Measure height of 3d block for [x y] point

Tags: matlab

I have following data:

```
kx = 20;
ky = 20;
k  = [kx ky];

PointsL = [
    [ 32   0   0] % P1
    [387   0   0]
    [475   0   0]
    [475  30   0]
    [602  30   0] % P5
    [602 220   0] 
    [475 220   0]
    [475 737   0]
    [387 737   0]
    [ 32 737   0] % P10
    [ 32 555   0]
    [  0 555   0]
    [  0 277   0]
    [ 27 277   0]
    [ 27 250   0] % P15
    [  0 250   0]
    [  0  57   0] 
    [ 32  57   0] % P18
];
PointsH = [
    [ 32   0 270] % P1
    [387   0 270]
    [475   0 183]
    [475  30 183]
    [602  30 183] % P5
    [602 220 183] 
    [475 220 183]
    [475 737 183]
    [387 737 270]
    [ 32 737 270] % P10
    [ 32 555 270]
    [  0 555 270]
    [  0 277 270]
    [ 27 277 270]
    [ 27 250 270] % P15
    [  0 250 270]
    [  0  57 270] 
    [ 32  57 270] % P18
];
```

`PointsL` are points of the lower surface - all with `z=0`.

`PointsH` are points of the higher surface - changable in z-axis.

All of them are representing points of room.

Following code draws 3d model:

```
plength = size(PointsL,1);
for i=1:plength
    if i == 1
        pl1 = PointsL(plength,:);
        ph1 = PointsH(plength,:);
    else
        pl1 = PointsL(i-1,:);
        ph1 = PointsH(i-1,:);
    end
    pl2 = PointsL(i,:);
    ph2 = PointsH(i,:);

    line([pl1(1) pl2(1)], [pl1(2) pl2(2)], [pl1(3) pl2(3)]);
    line([ph1(1) ph2(1)], [ph1(2) ph2(2)], [ph1(3) ph2(3)]);
    line([pl1(1) ph1(1)], [pl1(2) ph1(2)], [pl1(3) ph1(3)]);
end

p1 = PointsH(2,:);
p2 = PointsH(9,:);
line([p1(1) p2(1)], [p1(2) p2(2)], [p1(3) p2(3)]);

p1 = PointsH(4,:);
p2 = PointsH(7,:);
line([p1(1) p2(1)], [p1(2) p2(2)], [p1(3) p2(3)]);
```

[image: 3d model]

Is it possible to get height (`z` value) for given `x,y` values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was going to say that this could easily be done using `TriScatteredInterp()` on `PointsH`. I realised that it was not that simple to get it to produce what I wanted. I resorted to adding extra points and moving them around to create the right interpolation triangles.

I finally got something that can produce the z-value corresponding to the point (a,b).

Here is what I ended up doing...

```
epsilon = 1e-8;

PointsL_diff = epsilon*[
    [ -1   0   0] % P1
    [  0  -1   0]
    [  0  -1   0]
    [  1   0   0]
    [  0  -1   0] % added
    [  1  -1   0]
    [  1   0   0] % P5
    [  0  -1   0]
    [  1   1   0] 
    [  1   1   0]
    [  0   1   0]
    [  1   0   0] % added
    [  0   1   0]
    [ -1   0   0] % P10
    [  0   1   0] % added
    [ -1   1   0]
    [ -1   1   0]
    [ -1   0   0]
    [  0  -1   0] % added
    [ -1  -1   0]
    [ -1   1   0] % P15
    [ -1   0   0]
    [  0   1   0] % added
    [ -1  -1   0] 
    [ -1  -1   0] % P18
];

PointsL = [
    [ 32   0   0] % P1
    [ 32   0   0] % added
    [387   0   0]
    [475   0   0]
    [475   0   0] % added
    [475  30   0]
    [602  30   0] % P5
    [602  30   0] % added
    [602 220   0] 
    [475 220   0]
    [475 737   0]
    [475 737   0] % added
    [387 737   0]
    [ 32 737   0] % P10
    [ 32 737   0] % added
    [ 32 555   0]
    [  0 555   0]
    [  0 277   0]
    [  0 277   0] % added
    [ 27 277   0]
    [ 27 250   0] % P15
    [  0 250   0]
    [  0 250   0] % added
    [  0  57   0] 
    [ 32  57   0] % P18
];

PointsH = [
    [ 32   0 270] % P1
    [387   0 270]
    [475   0 183]
    [475  30 183]
    [602  30 183] % P5
    [602 220 183] 
    [475 220 183]
    [475+epsilon 220 183] % added
    [475 220+epsilon 183] % added
    [475 737 183]
    [387 737 270]
    [387 220 270] % added
    [ 32 737 270] % P10
    [ 32 555 270]
    [  0 555 270]
    [  0 277 270]
    [ 27 277 270]
    [ 27 250 270] % P15
    [  0 250 270]
    [  0  57 270] 
    [ 32  57 270] % P18
];

% plot bounds
x_min = -200;
x_max = 800;
y_min = -200;
y_max = 800;

newPointsL = PointsL + PointsL_diff;

x = [PointsH(:,1); newPointsL(:,1); x_min; x_max; x_min; x_max];
y = [PointsH(:,2); newPointsL(:,2); y_min; y_min; y_max; y_max];
z = [PointsH(:,3); newPointsL(:,3);     0;     0;     0;     0];

F = TriScatteredInterp(x,y,z); % default is linear interpolation

% find z-value for point (a,b)
a = 100;
b = 200;
z_value = F(a,b)

% generate mesh and plot surface
ti_x = x_min:10:x_max;
ti_y = y_min:10:y_max;
[qx,qy] = meshgrid(ti_x,ti_y);
qz = F(qx,qy);
mesh(qx,qy,qz);
hold on;
plot3(x,y,z,'o');
```

... and here is the figure the code produces:

[image: Mesh of simple building.]

Answer (score 0):

Quick general way:

Try `Data Cursor` option in the figure windows Tool bar.

And, if you want to do it programatically, follow this [link](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/controlling-plot-data-tips/).

Comment: I have to do it mathematically.

Comment: If you have to do it mathematically,then you have to create a `3×n Martix` of this plot artificially, and it'll be easy to find `z` for any given `x,y`.